# Error : Unique index or primary key violation in Spring Boot with the usage of Graphql?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I've implemented an example of the usage of **Graphql** in Spring Boot.
I got an error when I wrote the essential code snippets for both the **mutation** and the **query variables** part.

Here is my URL : `http://localhost:8081/graphql`
Here is my method type: `POST`

Here is my **mutation snippet** which is shown below.

```
mutation newHospital($hospitalInput: HospitalInput!) {
  newHospital(hospital: $hospitalInput){
    name
  }
}
```

Here is my **query variables** snippet which is shown below.

```
{
  "hospitalInput": {
    "name": "Hospital 6"
  }
}
```

Here is my error which is shown below.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation
```

Here is my **project** file : [Project Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootgraphql)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `@GeneratedValue` without specifying the concrete strategy. This resolves to `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`.

From your code

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
 private Integer id;
```

Try using `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

> IDENTITY Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary
> keys for the entity using a database identity column. AUTO Indicates
> that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy for
> the particular database. The`AUTO` generation strategy may
> expect a database resource to exist, or it may attempt to create one.
> A vendor may provide documentation on how to create such resources in
> the event that it does not support schema generation or cannot create
> the schema resource at runtime.